# Installing ios-sim 1.9.0 fails at preinstall during rake build

Tags: ios, node.js, build, rake

My ios-sim broke recently after installing system updates, and I'm trying to re-install it. Currently, it's not installed in my directory. When running `sudo npm install -g ios-sim`, I receive this error.

```
$ sudo npm install -g ios-sim
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ios-sim
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ios-sim
> ios-sim@1.9.0 preinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-sim
> rake build


events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: Cannot find module './ios-sim' from '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-sim'
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/rake/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:36:25
at load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rake/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:54:43)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/rake/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:60:22
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/rake/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:16:47
at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! ios-sim@1.9.0 preinstall: `rake build`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ios-sim@1.9.0 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ios-sim package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     rake build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ios-sim
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I've updated Node.JS to 1.4.3.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 5):

on my system install using node.js(v0.10.8)

```
$ sudo npm install -g ios-sim
```

also failed..

however

```
$ git clone git://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim.git
$ cd ios-sim
$ sudo rake install prefix=/usr/local
```

worked fine..

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set your developer active directory:

`sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Then you can install `ios-sim` as you would normally do: `npm install ios-sim -g`.

Comment: The only solution that got it working. Before, I had an error stating `Failed at the ios-sim@2.0.1 preinstall script 'rake build'`

Answer (score 1):

Check your version of Xcode, report it. Do you have Xcode Command-line tools installed also?
If you are on Mavericks:

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Does not work on OS X 10.9.5: "Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server".